# Which homotopy classes $S^3 \to S^2$ lift to embeddings $S^3 \to S^2 \times D^3$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, knot-theory

The question is, for a smooth embedding

$$f : S^3 \to S^2 \times D^3$$

one can compose the map $f$ with projection $\pi : S^2 \times D^3 \to S^2$, giving the map $\pi \circ f : S^3 \to S^2$.

Which homotopy classes of maps are realizable?

The analogous question where you vary the dimension of the disc, i.e.

$$ f : S^3 \to S^2 \times D^k $$

has immediate answers when $k \neq 3$.  When $k < 3$ the answer is only the constant map, and when $k > 3$ the answer is all homotopy classes, since $S^3$ lives in the boundary of $D^k$.  The $k < 3$ argument is a basic cut-and-paste topology argument, to argue that the projection must be null-homotopic.

I suspect the answer to this question exists in the literature, as you can view this as the problem of if one can "link" a linearly-embedded $S^2$ with a non-linearly embedded $S^3$ in $S^5$.   But I have looked through the old Haefliger-Zeeman literature on mixed-dimensional links, without much luck.  A short summary of the theory is here, written-up by Skopenkov: http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/High_codimension_links

A closely-related MO question is on the $k=2$ case, but where you let $f$ be an immersion.  This was answered positively in the comments. [Hopf fibration inside the retraction of R^4 minus line -> S^2?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24748/hopf-fibration-inside-the-retraction-of-r4-minus-line-s2)

edit: I suppose I could add I have a suspicion the answer is at least the subgroup of index two in $\pi_3 S^2 \simeq \mathbb Z$. At present I do not see how to obstruct a generator of $\pi_3 S^2$ being realizable.

Comment: What happens if you go down a dimension and consider embeddings $S^2\mapsto S^1\times D^2$? It seems like the answer there is only the constant maps, but there might be something I'm missing...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki:  Only constant maps in that case.  The $2^{nd}$ homotopy group of $S^1$ is trivial, so there is only the one homotopy-class available.

Comment: There's a Haefliger-style obstruction: Suppose the Hopf map $h:S^3\to S^2$ is the projection of an embedding $(h,e):S^3\to S^2\times\mathbb{R}^3$. (By the way, the literature might say that in this case $h$ is *3-prem*.) Let $\Delta(h)=\{(v,w)\in S^3 \mid v\neq w, h(v)=h(w)\}$. Then there is a $\mathbb{Z}/2$-equivariant map $\Delta(h)\to S^2$, where $\mathbb{Z}/2$ acts on $S^2$ antipodally and on $\Delta(h)$ by swapping factors, given by $(v,w)\mapsto (e(v)-e(w))/\|e(v)-e(w)\|$.

Comment: @MarkGrant in particular, as $h(v)=h(-v)$ we see that the formula $k(v)=(e(v)-e(-v))/\|e(v)-e(-v)\|$ gives an antipodal map $S^3\to S^2$, which is impossible.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Aha! So $h$ itself is not $3$-prem. I'm not quite seeing how to rule out that some $h'\simeq h$ is $3$-prem.

Answer (score 7):

This is not really an answer, but it provides some context.  We can consider $S^3$ as the space of unit quaternions, $S^2$ as the subspace of unit pure-imaginary quaternions, and $D^3$ as the space of pure-imaginary quaternions of norm at most one.  With these models, the generator of the group $\pi_3(S^2)$ is the map $\eta(u)=u\,i\,\overline{u}$.  The obvious way to try to define a corresponding map $f\colon S^3\to S^2\times D^3$ is to put $f(u)=(\eta(u),\text{Im}(u))$.  It is not hard to see that this is injective with a single exception, namely that $f(1)=f(-1)$.  So the question is whether we can eliminate this failure of injectivity by modifying $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Earlier I thought I had an argument that twice the Hopf map was realizable for an embedding $S^3 \to S^2 \times D^3$, but there was a mistake in my argument -- the map I suggested failed to be a smooth embedding.

Here is a more elementary observation on the problem.

**Proposition:** Given a smooth embedding $f : S^3 \to S^2 \times D^3$, then the projection map $\pi : S^2 \times D^3 \to S^2$ can not restrict to a locally-trivial fiber bundle on $f(S^3)$.

This proposition does not answer the question, but it provides some restrictions on answers.

The idea is to consider the simplest case.  Assume $\pi$ restricts to a locally-trivial fiber bundle on $f(S^3)$, and that $f(S^3)$ intersects the fibers of $\pi$ in unknotted loops. You could cite Hatcher's work here and conclude they must be linearly embedded loops.

This implies the Hopf fibration is classified by a map $S^2 \to V_{3,2} / SO_2$. We know the Hopf fibration is classified by the generator of $\pi_2 (V_{4,2} / SO_2)$, and $\pi_2 (V_{3,2}/SO_2)$ is the index two subgroup.

I believe this argument extends to the case the fibers are non-linearly embedded -- in that case you can argue the Euler class must be zero.  That said, there is probably a simpler way to rule out non-linearly embedded fibers.

**Comment:**

There is a map $f : S^3 \to S^2 \times D^3$ that is a 2-to-1 immersion, with the projection $S^3 \to S^2$ equal to the Hopf fibration.  The idea is that $S^3$ modulo antipodal points has a canonical identification with the unit tangent bundle of $S^2$, which is a subset of $S^2 \times D^3$.  I suppose using Neil's notation this would be the map $(\eta(u), \tau(u))$ where $\tau(u) = uj\overline{u}$.