# Does the singular cohomology for a metric space of finite topological dimension vanish in high dimensions?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mg.metric-geometry, cohomological-dimension

It is known that by applying the universal coefficient theorem, the singular cohomology of closed manifold with coefficient $\mathbb{Z}_2$ vanishes in high dimensions. But for a metric space $M$ with hausdorff dimension not larger than $n$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, it seems impossible to applied the universal coefficient theorem to prove that $H^{n+k}(M;\mathbb{Z}_2)=0$, $k\geq 1$, as $M$ is not necessarily a manifold. Whether there is a way to prove it? Or is there a counterexample?

Edit: By Johannes Hahn's suggestion, I change my question a bit to make it a better one.

The metric space $M$ above with hausdorff dimension not larger than $n$ should replaced by 
a compact metric space $M$ with topological dimension $n$. Other words will not be changed.

Comment: Considering that the Hausdorff dimension is a metric invariant, but not a topological one, and considering the connection between Hausdorff and inductive dimension (according to wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension#Properties_of_Hausdorff_dimension) one should really ask this question for the inductive dimension.

Comment: This is not really a counterargument as the metric-dependent Hausdorff dimension tends to be larger than the topological dimension.

Comment: I was going to suggest the Barratt-Milnor example (http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-02/S0002-9939-1962-0137110-9/) since that's a closed subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ with uncountable homology groups in all degrees. However, they detect this problem with rational homology and so it's not clear to me if the same method works for mod-2 homology.

Comment: @JohannesHahn Thank you for your advice. Indeed, hausdorff dimension is not a topological invariant. I will edit my question.

Comment: @ThiKu That's exactly the point: If the cohomology in degrees $> \dim_{ind}(X)$ vanish then they will also vanish in all degree $> \dim_{Haus}(X)$. On the other hand: Vanishing of cohomology is a topological invariant, so if one is able to prove a vanishing result w.r.t. the Hausdorff dimension, then one has also proven a vanishing result for all spaces homoemorphic to X.

Comment: @TylerLawson I think there's a follow-up paper by Barratt that might answer this.

Comment: @TylerLawson : it seems that the short proof given by Sergei Melikhov in http://arxiv.org/abs/0812.1407 adapts to Z/2 coefficients (maybe even simplifies, as Steenrod's realization holds in mod 2 homology).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the Hatcher answer in the post [dimension](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43400/topological-dimension-versus-cohomological-dimension)
is worth looking at for singular cohomology, and the Dranshnikov work for Cech Cohomology.

Comment: Thank you for your link. It is very helpful for my question!